# Always on top not working when focus dropped

Tags: unity, google-chrome, vlc

Using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, I'm seeing an issue I've seen on pretty much every OS so far except for Ubuntu, which is that the dock and top menu always overlay full screen applications when they are not in focus. I'm seeing this behaviour for a variety of things, including VLC Media Player, Sublime Text 3, Google Chrome on YouTube and Twitch.

It also doesn't seem to happen for a while after booting. Like for 20-30 minutes everything is fine, and suddenly I'll open a new video or so and it will stop working properly. It is also intermittent when it is bugged, I sometimes have managed to re-focus a few times and make it work again.

Has anyone experienced this and does anyone know how to fix it? It's really quite infuriating.

**Update**

It seems that if you have a fullscreen application on one monitor, making another application fullscreen on another monitor causes the problem to "stop". So it looks like when a fullscreen application is focused a system flag is set which tells the taskbar to hide. Not sure at this point whether this behaviour can be overridden.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a problem to me. If the fullscreen window doesn't have focus, isn't that because you're doing other things and would want to have access to the dock and top menu?

Comment: I am indeed doing other things, but on other screens. In this instance, I'm watching twitch / movie / youtube whilst playing games / doing work... If I'm watching games such as DotA2, the scoreboard at the top is not visible because of the menu bar which is pretty much game-breaking. MS fixed the same issue in Windows 8, but it seems at the same time Canonical have implemented it on Ubuntu... :(